# centOs : system time getting reset back to UTC after changing it using timedatectl

Tags: centos, systemd, ntp, ntpd, journalctl

I have a Centos machine with version 7.  I am trying to change the system time using the `timedatectl` command. The time gets changed but after a few seconds it gets reset back to it's original time.

```
[root@abcd ~]# timedatectl
  Local time: Tue 2018-10-16 05:51:30 UTC
  Universal time: Tue 2018-10-16 05:51:30 UTC
  RTC time: Wed 2019-10-16 03:40:38
  Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
  NTP enabled: no
  NTP synchronized: no
  RTC in local TZ: no
  DST active: n/a
[root@abcd ~]#
[root@abcd ~]# timedatectl set-time "2019-10-16 05:51:30"
[root@abcd ~]# timedatectl
  Local time: Wed 2019-10-16 05:51:32 UTC
  Universal time: Wed 2019-10-16 05:51:32 UTC
  RTC time: Wed 2019-10-16 05:51:33
  Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
  NTP enabled: no
  NTP synchronized: no
  RTC in local TZ: no
  DST active: n/a
[root@abcd ~]# timedatectl
    Local time: Tue 2018-10-16 05:54:38 UTC
    Universal time: Tue 2018-10-16 05:54:38 UTC
    RTC time: Wed 2019-10-16 05:52:35
    Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
    NTP enabled: no
    NTP synchronized: no
    RTC in local TZ: no
    DST active: n/a
[root@abcd ~]#
```

When I check the `systemd` logs using `journalctl -f` command, I notice that there is a process which is changing the system time to UTC after 80 sec approximately. I have no clue what this process is. Those logs are

```
Oct 16 06:01:39 abcd systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Oct 16 06:02:58  abcd systemd[1]: Time has been changed
```

How do I debug this ?

Comment: What is there to debug? Looks like it works as intended to me.

Comment: It doesn't. If I change the timezone, it still goes back and sets it to UTC. The question is, what is the process/daemon which is doing this change.

Comment: Try to check using ps -ef  | grep time*

Comment: @user1851006 Did you ever figure this out?  I'm seeing a similar behavior on another version of Linux.

Answer (score 3):

just try setting timezone.

```
# timedatectl set-timezone *your timezone*
```

Comment: You are setting the time.  You need to set the timeZONE as @aroN indicates.  Alternatively, you can change the timezone by deleting `/etc/localtime` and creating it as a new symlink as here:  `~ 0$ ls -l /etc/localtime`

`lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 27 Sep  7 12:57 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/MST7MDT`

Comment: Changing timezone doesn't work either. If I change the timezone to say, CDT, it sets it back to UTC after 80 sec. I want to know which process/daemon is doing this

Answer (score 1):

If this is a virtual guest, some guest integrations sync the time of the host to the guest. Check that the hypervisor is syncing time with NTP, so this time is at least correct.

If you want to run in the wrong time for some reason, please edit your question to add why, and which virtual platform you use.

Comment: This isn't a virtual guest.

Comment: You can trace system calls to find out what is doing this.  On Linux, try using auditd to  log stime() and  settimeofday().